# Twilio Chat Token issue

Tags: twilio, chat

I am integrating Twilio Chat into my web app,
however, when I am passing my access token which is generated by server,
it shows this error.

[image]

My code snippet as below:

```
fetch(
      URL,
      {
        headers: { "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" },
        method: "POST",
        body: `identity=${encodeURIComponent(username)}`,
      }
    )
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then(({ token }) => {
        Chat.Client.create(token)
          .then((client) => {
            setupChatClient(client);
          })
          .catch(handleError);
      })
      .catch(handleError);
```

I did pass `username` as identity when invoking function, and API did return token, but I just don't know why it's not happy :(

Comment: You should able to paste the Chat Token in https://jwt.io and take a look.

Comment: Can you share the code you are using to create the chat token?